# Python + Ubuntu Linux + nohup error: [1]+ Exit

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, nohup

I have a python script, `practice_one.py`, that I’d like it to run forever in Ubuntu Linux, and has the following:

```
while True:
   #    Code
```

And I attempted `nohup python practice_one.py &` but got the message `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’`.

Then when I hit the enter key, the outputs another message: `[1]+ Exit  nohup python practice_one.py`

How come it just exits automatically? What could I be doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Attempted:
`nohup python practice_one.py </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

And get `[1] 61122` then when I press enter I got `[1]+ Exit    nohup python practice_one.py </dev/null &>/dev/null &`

It used to work but now exits.. What could be the issue now?

Comment: Look into `nohup.out` for any error message.

Comment: You do have any code in the body of that loop, right?

Comment: I would start working on this issue by adding a python shebang on the script, such as `#!/usr/bin/env python`. Next, I would run this `bash` command to make sure that the script is executable for all users: `chmod +x practice_one.py`. Next, I would add a simple write to an external file right after the shebang but BEFORE anything else, such as `with open("my_file.txt", "w") as file: file.write("OK")`, and then I would try to run the file again and see if the external file had the "ok" printed on it. If you try this all, reply to me in this tread with the result so I can try to help further

Comment: Could you post your script somewhere? Maybe it's possible to learn something new.

Comment: If "It used to work but now exits.." then the problem cannot be in the driver. Everyone has been there done that :-)

Answer (score 9):

I usually face this in **three** cases:

1. When an exception in the while loop occurs.
2. When somewhere in the code I have pdb.set_trace() which is a debugging breakpoint.
3. When somewhere in the code, input from user is requested as in *raw_input("Please enter something: ")*

Check your code to exclude these three causes.

Don't worry about the first message, it is just informing you that nohup is in work.

**EDIT**

4. Before running the script with `nohup` make sure that the script itself works fine (This would actually be the first thing to try).

Comment: This is the "answer", because the question contains too little detail to say otherwise. My bet is #4.... :)

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you'd better use `double fork magic` to run your long-running program as a daemon instead of `nohup`. It is easy to debug and your program doesn't need external tools like `nohup`.

daemon.py

```
import sys
import os

# double fork magic
def daemonize():
    os.umask(0)

    try:
        pid = os.fork()
    except OSError:
        sys.exit(0)
    if pid > 0:
        sys.exit(0)
    os.setsid()

    try:
        pid = os.fork()
    except OSError:
        sys.exit(0)
    if pid > 0:
        os._exit(0)

    os.chdir('/')

    import resource     # Resource usage information.
    maxfd = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE)[1]
    if (maxfd == resource.RLIM_INFINITY):
        maxfd = 1024

    # Iterate through and close all file descriptors.
    for fd in range(0, maxfd):
        try:
            os.close(fd)
        except OSError:   # ERROR, fd wasn't open to begin with (ignored)
            pass

    fd = os.open(os.devnull, os.O_RDWR)
    os.dup2(fd, sys.stdin.fileno())
    os.dup2(fd, sys.stdout.fileno())
    os.dup2(fd, sys.stderr.fileno())
```

test.py

```
from daemon import daemonize
import time


def test():
    while True:
        time.sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    daemonize() # you could comment this line before you make sure your program run as you expect
    test()
```

Now, using `python test.py` to make it run as a daemon and you could use `ps aux | grep test.py` to check it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Ash, you're facing some trouble within your script.

I've tested your scenario and I assure you **nohup isn't the problem**:

**Python code**

```
$ cat practice_one.py
while True:
   print 'ok'
```

**Nohup execution**

```
m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU ~/python_excercises/nohup-python
$ nohup python practice_one.py &
[1] 10552

m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU ~/python_excercises/nohup-python
$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'

m.ortiz.montealegre@CPX-XYR3G1DTHBU ~/python_excercises/nohup-python
$ ps
      PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY         UID    STIME COMMAND
    10552   15248   10552       9992  cons1    6758389 16:52:27 /usr/bin/python2.7
```

So, try simplifying your script operations to find out which one is the problem by commenting the code and test until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Set execution permission on the script

```
chmod +x practice_one.py
```

Try closing all the file descriptors

```
nohup ./practice_one.py <&- 1>&-  2>&- &
```

Answer (score 1):

The first is not an error - it just means that nohup will capture STDOUT and store it in nohup.out. If you want to mute everything use:

```
nohup python practice_one.py &>/dev/null
```

Comment: Everything got muted but how do I check to see if it is in fact being ran?

Comment: Ummm, `ps aux | grep python` ?

Comment: Why is it that strings like 4EAST is recognized as 4%EF%BF%EF%BF%BD etc.

Comment: That depends on text and shell encoding, terminal representation etc. plus is a bit out of scope of your original question.

Comment: when I run the command to see if nohup is being ran, what should it say on the list? Don't believe I see any nohup

Comment: The above command will show you a list of processes with python in their name. One of them should end with something like: `/usr/bin/python practice_one.py` (nohup won't be mentioned). That is if your script didn't exit in the mean time (and since we're muting the output above we cannot know why).

Answer (score 1):

In the code, there should be a break. What i mean by that is; You should have a exit state even though you're not going to reach it. In the exist state, you can specify to make the while loop become true.

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop

I'd recommend to use a for loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just met this issue. I am pretty sure there is something wrong with your code. Otherwise, there should not be the exit message.

Answer (score -1):

This is a normal behaviour of nohup. 
To avoid this try:

```
nohup python my_script.py </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

Comment: Do not solve the problem... (the fact that the script exit)